# How to call C function with two-dimensional array argument in Swift?

Tags: ios, c, arrays, swift

In my swift program, I have successfully called a C function with 1-dim array argument. But when I try to call a C function with 2-dim array argument in Swift, it prompts an error as below:

```
'[([(Double)])]' is not convertible to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)>'
```

Here is my calling in swift:

```
var tSet  = [[Double]](count: 18, repeatedValue: [Double](count: 5,repeatedValue: Double(0.0)))
getTrainSet(sub_xlist, tSet)
```

and my C function definition:

```
void getTrainSet(const double *ax, double trainSet[18][5])
```

It seems something wrong with the initialization of 2-dim array in Swift. Anyone could help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void getTrainSet(const double *ax, double trainSet[18][5])
```

is translated to Swift as:

```
func getTrainSet(ax: UnsafePointer<Double>, trainSet: UnsafeMutablePointer<(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)>)
```

### Solution1

Make an `Array` of `(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)`:

```
var sub_xlist: Double = 0
var tSet = [(Double,Double,Double,Double,Double)](count: 18, repeatedValue: (0,0,0,0,0))
getTrainSet(&sub_xlist, &tSet)
```

and get the results like:

```
tSet[1].3 // equivalent to `tSet[1][3]` in C
```

### Solution2

In C, `double trainSet[18][5]` is just a buffer of `90` (`18 * 5`) `double`s. You can make `[Double]` with `90` elements and pass it as `UnsafeMutablePointer`:

```
var sub_xlist: Double = 0
var tSet = [Double](count: 18 * 5, repeatedValue: 0)
getTrainSet(&sub_xlist, UnsafeMutablePointer(tSet))
```

And you can get the results like:

```
let row = 1
let col = 3
tSet[row * 5 + col] // equivalent to `tSet[row][col]` in C
```

Answer (score 1):

This C function has this type in Swift

```
void getTrainSet(const double *ax, double trainSet[2][2]) // C
getTrainSet(ax: UnsafePointer<Double>, 
            trainSet: UnsafeMutablePointer<(Double, Double)>)  //Swift
```

To convert `var` to `UnsafePointer` you have to use `&` when passing it to function

```
var sub_xlist = 10.0
getTrainSet(&sub_xlist)
```

Two dimensional array are converted to a Array of Tuples in Swift. Second dimension determinate how many elements will be in the Tuple
**Example**:

```
double a[2][2] // In C
[(Double, Double)]() // In Swift

Int a[18][3] // In C
[(Int, Int, Int)]() // In Swift
```

`UnsafeMutablePointer<(Double, Double)>` - is an array of Tuples with type `(Double, Double)`
In your example `trainSet` is an Array of Tuples with 5 Double elements

**Solution** :

```
var sub_xlist = 10.0
var p: UnsafeMutablePointer<(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)> = nil
var tuples  = [(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)]()
getTrainSet(&sub_xlist, &tuples)
getTrainSet(&sub_xlist, p)
```

Read more here [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)

Comment: Thank you Koval for point the source of this error.I've fixed it by using an one-dimensional array.